# Multi-select select option value issue Options

Tags: debugging, multiselect-attribute

I have some problem with multi-select list in `catalog/product/view.phtml`

I've tried to echo only "selected" values but without result, this code outputs all values no matter what I choose from select-list.

The frontend Magento select list looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="17">230V</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="18">24VAC</option>
    <option value="20">24VAC/DC</option>
    <option value="19">24VDC</option>
</select>
```

Here is also my code from `view.phtml` file (product view):

```
function getSelectAttributeValues($attrCode)  {
    $attributeCode = $attrCode;

    // build and filter the product collection
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') 
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('notnull' => true))
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);

    $usedAttributeValues = array_unique($products->getColumnValues($attributeCode));

    // fetch the attribute model
    $attributeModel = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

    // map the option id's to option labels
    $usedAttributeValues = $attributeModel->getSource()->getOptionText(
        implode(',', $usedAttributeValues)
    );     


    if (is_array($usedAttributeValues)) {
        return implode(', ', $usedAttributeValues);
    } else { 
        return $usedAttributeValues;
    }                       
}
```

Please help me, I'll be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Hi Pawel and welcome to MageOverflow. Can you please give a little bit context what you are trying and what doesn't work? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Hi Fabian,

on this product http://frakta.he-hosting.de/silence-4-nm-60.html in Produktsmerkale there is "Spannung" parameters.
In admin panel I've checked only 230V and 24VAC in multi-select list but Mageto outputs every value from this list except only selected values.

What I want to do is getting only selected values on frontend product view :)